# Installing Deeptools in R

Tags: r, bedtools

```r
> install.packages("bedtools")
```

Also tried this with bedtoolsr. Is there a way to force install? I am using version R 4.2.2.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘bedtools’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Comment: `deepTools` is a Python package. How have you installed that package for use in R?  Regarding `bedtools`, if you install it and have it in your PATH, you can use the `bedr` package to access the tool set within R.

Comment: There are several bedtools wrapper, mostly found on and installed through https://www.bioconductor.org. I fear you have to decide which one you need and ideally describe what you want to do with it.

Comment: It is certainly difficult to search for packages for the R language. I tend to use one or both of `"r"` (quotes required) or `CRAN` in my searches, where the latter will look in the official R repositories (not necessarily bioconductor, for instance). The use of quotes around a parameter in google search mandates that it be included in the results, so [`"cran" "bedtools"`](https://www.google.com/search?q="cran"+"bedtools") returns the `bedr` package at the top of the list, ymmv.

Comment: @Seth I tried this install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("PhanstielLab/bedtoolsr", force = TRUE)
library(bedtoolsr) and got error sh: bedtools: command not found
Warning in value[[3L]](cond) :
  bedtools does not appear to be installed or not in your PATH. If it is installed, please add it to your PATH or run:
options(bedtools.path = "/path/to/")
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
sh: bedtools: command not found
  bedtools does not appear to be installed or not in your PATH.
options(bedtools.path = "/path/to/")

Comment: [This link](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/HelloRanges.html) and more specificall [here](https://bioconductor.org/about/release-announcements/) have version-specific installation instructions.